# Splitting strings based on multiple delimiters does not yield consistent result

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a file type with many rows containing information as follows:

```
  P087 = ( 4.000000000000000E+001,-6.250000000000000E-001 )
  P088 = ( 4.000000000000000E+001, 0.000000000000000E+000 )
```

I'm reading this file line by line using

```
fo = open(FileName, 'r')
for line in fo:
    #do stuff to line
```

I'd like to see how to split each line to give lists as follows:

```
[87, 40.0,-0.625]
[88, 40.0, 0.0]
```

I tried splitting using `python`'s regular `.split()` method but it doesn't split the lines consistently, yielding varying list lengths for each line.

I also investigated `re.split()` using stuff like `re.split([ = ( ]|,)` but that didn't work either. I'm also not a big regular expression user (though I know they are very powerful) which explains why I'm having a hard time finding the right one.

I guess I need to delimit the lines by  `' = ( '` and `','` though I'm really not sure how to do it such that the resulting lists are consistent. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, you mean that each line will be like the string : `'P087 = ( 4.000000000000000E+001,-6.250000000000000E-001 )'`?

Comment: Yes, exactly what I mean

Comment: Could you regex the whole string and use a few capture groups to get out the values you want? (see https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#grouping)

Comment: Try doing a findall using `[^ (),=P\r\n]+` on each line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
for line in fo:
    parts = re.match(r'\s*P(\d+)\s*=\s*[(]\s*([^ ,]*)[ ,]+([^ ,]*)[ )]*',line).groups()
    print([int(parts[0]), float(parts[1]), float(parts[2])])
```

The `re.match` is used to extract the important parts, then each is parsed to the appropriate type to be printed.

Comment: works like a charm. Would you have another matching string for something like `SE104 = ( P1555, P1378, P1379, P1380, P1377, P1363, P1362, P1361, P1367, P1371, P1372, P1373, P1364, P1365, P1366 )` to convert to `[104, 1555, 1378, 1378 ....]` and so forth? all are integers in this case

Comment: Also what does the `([^ ,]*)` part mean? Are you using the caret here as a negate symbol? i.e group anything that is not a comma?

Comment: `([^ ,]*)` captures a sequence of characters that are not either a space or a comma.

Answer (score 4):

Using [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) for parsing the tuple string:

```
import ast
import re

with open(FileName, 'r') as f:
    out = [
        [int(re.findall('(?<=P)\d+', k)[0]), *ast.literal_eval(v.strip())]
        for k, v in [line.split('=') for line in f]
    ]
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution without regex:

```
def parse_line(line):
    first, second = line.split(',')
    ind = int(first.split()[0][2:])
    num1 = float(first.split()[-1])
    num2 = float(second.split()[0])
    return [ind, num1, num2]

line = 'P087 = ( 4.000000000000000E+001,-6.250000000000000E-001 )'
print(parse_line(line))

line = ' P088 = ( 4.000000000000000E+001, 0.000000000000000E+000 )'
print(parse_line(line))
```

Answer (score 1):

The following regular expression will extract all the lines from your file:

```
c = re.compile(r'\s*P(\d+)\s*=\s*\(\s*([\d\.\+\-E]+)\s*,\s*([\d\.\+\-E]+)\s*\)')
lines = list(c.findall(x))
```

where `x` is the string that is your file content.

Answer (score 1):

It's not always a good idea to use it, but `eval` can be ideal in these situations:

```
from ast import literal_eval
result = []
for line in fo:
  item = []
  name, val = line.split('=')
  item.append(name.strip())
  item.extend(literal_eval(val.strip()))
  result.append(item)

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Regex**:  [`[-0-9.]+[-E+0-9]*`](https://regex101.com/r/FTSU5b/1) or `[-\d.]+[-E+\d]*`

Details:

- `[]` Match a single character present in the list
- `+` Matches between `one` and `unlimited` times
- `*` Matches between `zero` and `unlimited` times

**Python code**:

```
import re

def arr_num(text):
    array = []
    for n in re.finditer(r'[-0-9.]+[-E+0-9]*', text):
        array.append(n.group().isdigit() and int(n.group()) or float(n.group()))
    return array
```

Output:

```
arr_num("SE104 = ( P1555, P1378, P1379, P1380, P1377, P1363, P1362, P1361, P1367, P1371, P1372, P1373, P1364, P1365, P1366 )")
>>> [104, 1555, 1378, 1379, 1380, 1377, 1363, 1362, 1361, 1367, 1371, 1372, 1373, 1364, 1365, 1366]

arr_num("P087 = ( 4.000000000000000E+001,-6.250000000000000E-001 )")
>>> [87, 40.0, -0.625]
```